# Are free submodules of finitely generated modules finitely generated?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, free-modules

Are free submodules of finitely generated modules finitely generated?

It feels like this should be true because it seems weird that a finitely generated module will have an infinite linearly independent subset, but I am unable to prove it.

Assume that the ring is commutative with unity.

Comment: In general a finitely gennerated module can have a submodule which is not finitely generated, in this case the ring must have to be non-Noetherian. For example $A=k[x_1, x_2, \cdots], M=(x_1, x_2, \cdots)$ (infinite variables, $k$ is a field). So I guess your question is whether a f.g. module contains a free submodule of infinite rank or not. Because if it is of finite rank, then it is already generated by finitely many elements.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you. I edited the question to make the necessary changes.

Comment: Every non-noetherian ring is an example of a cyclic module with an infinitely generated submodule, so it seems like it might not be too big of a leap for one to exist where the infinitely generated submodule is free.  But maybe something rules this out...

Comment: This was not asked, but I think it is nice to point out that this fails in the non-commutative case. If $F$ is a non-finitely generated free group and $\mathbb{Z}F$ is its integral group ring, then the (cyclic) module $\mathbb{Z}F$ contains a non-finitely generated free submodule, namely the augmentation ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $R$ is a non-trivial commutative ring and $M$ is generated by $n$ elements then $n$ does not contain a free submodule of rank greater than $n$.

To see this assume we have an injection $R^m \hookrightarrow M$ and a surjection $R^n \twoheadrightarrow M$.  As $R^m$ is free, the map to $M$ factors through $R^n$ and we get an injection $R^m \hookrightarrow R^n$.  As $R$ is nonzero commutative this implies $m \leq n$ (see, for example, [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1988-103-04/S0002-9939-1988-0954974-5/S0002-9939-1988-0954974-5.pdf)).

Comment: Nice.  Other proofs of the rank inequality can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30860/39640) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/136/39640).

Comment: Addition: The reason why "the map to $M$ factors through $R^n$" is a free module is a projective module.